# Add DataGridViews to Form programatically

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem and I'm searching for some ideas how to implement it. I have a DataGridView with ComboBoxColumns, ButtonColumns and TextBoxColumns.

Below I have two Buttons one to add a new DataGridView and one to delete the lastly created DataGridView.

How can I achieve it that a new DataGridView will be added below the already existing DataGridView when clicking add Button and deleted when clicking delete button.

Code for creating new DataGridView, but I want every time a new DataGridView, actually it is only creating a second and then adding columns at the end.

```
private void add(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            dataGridView2.Visible = true;
            dataGridView2.Width = 725;
            dataGridView2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            dataGridView2.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
            dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            dataGridView2.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            dataGridView2.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;

            for (var i = 0; i < rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                if (rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].GetType().Name == "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn")
                {
                    var cmbColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                    cmbColumn.DataPropertyName = rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    cmbColumn.HeaderText = rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    cmbColumn.ValueMember = rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    cmbColumn.DisplayMember = rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    cmbColumn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(cmbColumn);
                }
                if (rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].GetType().Name == "DataGridViewButtonColumn")
                {
                    var btnColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                    btnColumn.DataPropertyName = rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    btnColumn.HeaderText = rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    btnColumn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(btnColumn);
                }

                if (rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].GetType().Name == "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn")
                {
                    var txtColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    txtColumn.DataPropertyName = rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    txtColumn.HeaderText = rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    dataGridView2.Columns.Add(txtColumn);
                }
            }

            dataGridView2.Location = new Point(rb_insert_manually_datagridview_detailed.Location.X, rb_insert_manually_btn_new_binder.Location.Y + 40);
            this.Controls.Add(dataGridView2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.Error, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

To remove a DataGrid I use actually Visible but it isn't working, and on the commented out version it throws the Exception

```
private void delete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            /*                dataGridView2.Columns.Remove("col1");
                            dataGridView2.Columns.Remove("col2");
                            dataGridView2.Columns.Remove("col3");
                            dataGridView2.Columns.Remove("col4");
                            dataGridView2.Columns.Remove("col5");
                            dataGridView2.Columns.Remove("col6");*/
            dataGridView2.Visible = false;
        }
        catch
        {

                MessageBox.Show("Kann letzen Binder nicht löschen", "Warnung", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
}
```

I'm thankful for every help, idea.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code thus we can help you.

Comment: I see no code that actually creates a 2nd DGV. What is dataGridView2 ? The 1st one or the new one? How many should there be allowed? To place dgv2 below dgv1 set dgv.Top = dgv1.Bottom + 1. To place it below a button use btn.Bottom + 1..

Comment: dataGridView2 is the one i create with the Column specs of the first one. So i check the column properties of the first one and create a second DGV with same properties